# WPF User Control on top of WebBrowser control in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, webbrowser-control

I have been browsing through the problem of rendering WPF UserControl (as parent Control) on top of WPF WebBrowserControl.

Same scenario, when I am trying to implement the same on Window (as parent control), on top of WPF WebBrowser, I am successful. But in case of WPF UserControl, I am not able to do it. (i.e. Unable to bring User Control on top of Web Browser but able to bring Window on top of WPF WebBrowser Control).

Problem is termed as "AirSpace Problem", which is removed by using concept of HWND.

Can any one help on the same ?

Code for Window as parent (Working Fine):

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="WebBrowserDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WebBrowserDemo"
    >
<DockPanel>
    <Grid>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        MinWidth="80" Margin="3" Content="Send" Click="Button_Click_1"  />
    </Grid>
    <Grid>

        <local:AirspacePopup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=webBrowser}"  x:Name="PopupNew" 
                     FollowPlacementTarget="True"
                     AllowOutsideScreenPlacement="True"
                     ParentWindow="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                     IsOpen="True"
                     AllowsTransparency="True"
                     Placement="Center"
                     Width="{Binding ElementName=googleBrowser, Path=ActualWidth}"
                     Height="{Binding ElementName=googleBrowser, Path=ActualHeight}">
            <Grid>
                <local:UserControl1></local:UserControl1>
            </Grid>
        </local:AirspacePopup>
        <WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" Loaded="WebBrowser_Loaded"/>

    </Grid>

</DockPanel>
```

Custom Control Class (AirSpace Class):

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace WebBrowserDemo
{
    public class AirspacePopup : Popup
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTopmostProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsTopmost",
                                        typeof(bool),
                                        typeof(AirspacePopup),
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsTopmostChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FollowPlacementTargetProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FollowPlacementTarget",
                                                typeof(bool),
                                                typeof(AirspacePopup),
                                                new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowOutsideScreenPlacementProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AllowOutsideScreenPlacement",
                                                typeof(bool),
                                                typeof(AirspacePopup),
                                                new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentWindowProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ParentWindow",
                                                typeof(Window),
                                                typeof(AirspacePopup),
                                                new UIPropertyMetadata(null, ParentWindowPropertyChanged));
        private static void OnIsTopmostChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            AirspacePopup airspacePopup = source as AirspacePopup;
            airspacePopup.SetTopmostState(airspacePopup.IsTopmost);
        }

        private static void ParentWindowPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            AirspacePopup airspacePopup = source as AirspacePopup;
            airspacePopup.ParentWindowChanged();
        }

        private bool? m_appliedTopMost;
        private bool m_alreadyLoaded;
        private Window m_parentWindow;

        public AirspacePopup()
        {
            Loaded += OnPopupLoaded;
            Unloaded += OnPopupUnloaded;

            DependencyPropertyDescriptor descriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(PlacementTargetProperty, typeof(AirspacePopup));
            descriptor.AddValueChanged(this, PlacementTargetChanged);
        }

        public bool IsTopmost
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsTopmostProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsTopmostProperty, value); }
        }
        public bool FollowPlacementTarget
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(FollowPlacementTargetProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FollowPlacementTargetProperty, value); }
        }
        public bool AllowOutsideScreenPlacement
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(AllowOutsideScreenPlacementProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AllowOutsideScreenPlacementProperty, value); }
        }
        public Window ParentWindow
        {
            get { return (Window)GetValue(ParentWindowProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ParentWindowProperty, value); }
        }

        private void ParentWindowChanged()
        {
            if (ParentWindow != null)
            {
                ParentWindow.LocationChanged += (sender, e2) =>
                {
                    UpdatePopupPosition();
                };
                ParentWindow.SizeChanged += (sender, e2) =>
                {
                    UpdatePopupPosition();
                };
            }
        }
        private void PlacementTargetChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement placementTarget = this.PlacementTarget as FrameworkElement;
            if (placementTarget != null)
            {
                placementTarget.SizeChanged += (sender2, e2) =>
                {
                    UpdatePopupPosition();
                };
            }
        }

        private void UpdatePopupPosition()
        {
            FrameworkElement placementTarget = this.PlacementTarget as FrameworkElement;
            FrameworkElement child = this.Child as FrameworkElement;

            if (placementTarget!=null && PresentationSource.FromVisual(placementTarget) != null &&
                AllowOutsideScreenPlacement == true)
            {
                double leftOffset = CutLeft(placementTarget);
                double topOffset = CutTop(placementTarget);
                double rightOffset = CutRight(placementTarget);
                double bottomOffset = CutBottom(placementTarget);
                Debug.WriteLine(bottomOffset);
                this.Width = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(leftOffset, rightOffset) + placementTarget.ActualWidth);
                this.Height = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(topOffset, bottomOffset) + placementTarget.ActualHeight);

                if (child != null)
                {
                    child.Margin = new Thickness(leftOffset, topOffset, rightOffset, bottomOffset);
                }
            }
            if (FollowPlacementTarget == true)
            {
                this.HorizontalOffset += 0.01;
                this.HorizontalOffset -= 0.01;
            }
        }
        private double CutLeft(FrameworkElement placementTarget)
        {
            Point point = placementTarget.PointToScreen(new Point(0, placementTarget.ActualWidth));
            return Math.Min(0, point.X);
        }
        private double CutTop(FrameworkElement placementTarget)
        {
            Point point = placementTarget.PointToScreen(new Point(placementTarget.ActualHeight, 0));
            return Math.Min(0, point.Y);
        }
        private double CutRight(FrameworkElement placementTarget)
        {
            Point point = placementTarget.PointToScreen(new Point(0, placementTarget.ActualWidth));
            point.X += placementTarget.ActualWidth;
            return Math.Min(0, SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth - (Math.Max(SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth, point.X)));
        }
        private double CutBottom(FrameworkElement placementTarget)
        {
            Point point = placementTarget.PointToScreen(new Point(placementTarget.ActualHeight, 0));
            point.Y += placementTarget.ActualHeight;
            return Math.Min(0, SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight - (Math.Max(SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight, point.Y)));
        }

        private void OnPopupLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (m_alreadyLoaded)
                return;

            m_alreadyLoaded = true;

            if (Child != null)
            {
                Child.AddHandler(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnChildPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown), true);
            }

            m_parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);

            if (m_parentWindow == null)
                return;

            m_parentWindow.Activated += OnParentWindowActivated;
            m_parentWindow.Deactivated += OnParentWindowDeactivated;
        }

        private void OnPopupUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (m_parentWindow == null)
                return;
            m_parentWindow.Activated -= OnParentWindowActivated;
            m_parentWindow.Deactivated -= OnParentWindowDeactivated;
        }

        private void OnParentWindowActivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetTopmostState(true);
        }

        private void OnParentWindowDeactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsTopmost == false)
            {
                SetTopmostState(IsTopmost);
            }
        }

        private void OnChildPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            SetTopmostState(true);
            if (!m_parentWindow.IsActive && IsTopmost == false)
            {
                m_parentWindow.Activate();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnOpened(EventArgs e)
        {
            SetTopmostState(IsTopmost);
            base.OnOpened(e);
        }

        private void SetTopmostState(bool isTop)
        {
            // Don’t apply state if it’s the same as incoming state
            if (m_appliedTopMost.HasValue && m_appliedTopMost == isTop)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (Child == null)
                return;

            var hwndSource = (PresentationSource.FromVisual(Child)) as HwndSource;

            if (hwndSource == null)
                return;
            var hwnd = hwndSource.Handle;

            RECT rect;

            if (!GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rect))
                return;

            Debug.WriteLine("setting z-order " + isTop);

            if (isTop)
            {
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, rect.Left, rect.Top, (int)Width, (int)Height, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
            }
            else
            {
                // Z-Order would only get refreshed/reflected if clicking the
                // the titlebar (as opposed to other parts of the external
                // window) unless I first set the popup to HWND_BOTTOM
                // then HWND_TOP before HWND_NOTOPMOST
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_BOTTOM, rect.Left, rect.Top, (int)Width, (int)Height, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP, rect.Left, rect.Top, (int)Width, (int)Height, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
                SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, rect.Left, rect.Top, (int)Width, (int)Height, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
            }

            m_appliedTopMost = isTop;
        }

        // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
        // Imports etc. with their naming rules

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,
        int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

        static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);

        private const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
        const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
        const UInt32 SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
        const UInt32 SWP_NOREDRAW = 0x0008;
        const UInt32 SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;

        const UInt32 SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020; /* The frame changed: send WM_NCCALCSIZE */
        const UInt32 SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
        const UInt32 SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080;
        const UInt32 SWP_NOCOPYBITS = 0x0100;
        const UInt32 SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200; /* Don’t do owner Z ordering */
        const UInt32 SWP_NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400; /* Don’t send WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING */

        const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS =
            SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOREDRAW | SWP_NOSENDCHANGING;

        // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming   
    }
}
```

UserControl.xaml :

```
<UserControl x:Class="WebBrowserDemo.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="I AM USER CONTROl"></TextBlock>
        <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Green" Margin="100"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Need to implement same type of Scenario , with UserControl. Please help somebody.

Comment: Unfortunately, its not possible with Webbrowser Control in WPF.  See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35547991/2819451)

Comment: It seems we can do it in case of Window. Can we try for the same with UserControl ??

Comment: No,  Whatever it is, it will create a wrapper at the top.

Comment: I fully support your views ... But Can we consider the aspect shared in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418526/wpf-rendering-problem-with-hwnd-children-in-the-way/2421640#2421640

Comment: Yes.  there are some work around which you can try. .  But wont be exact solution.

Comment: Can you please any of those